# jQuery .attr() and .val() not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, input

I have a page which loads several rows inside a table like so:

```
<tr>
{...}
  <td>
    <input type="text" id="rate-adjusted-<?php echo $row_count; ?>" name="section_line_rate_adjusted_01[]" value="{{ number_format($allowableSectionLine->rate_adjusted_line1, 2) }}" disabled />
  </td>
{...}
</tr>
```

This outputs:

```
<td>
   <input type="text" id="rate-adjusted-2" name="section_line_rate_adjusted_01[]" value="20,000.00" disabled=""><br>
</td>
```

The user now has a choice via an input element to set a percentage which gets applied and adds 110% to another calculated value.

**Javascript:**

```
function updateRateAdjusted(percentage) {

  jQuery("[id^=rate-adjusted-]").each(function(key) {

    var rate = jQuery('#rate-' + key).val();
    var rate_adjusted = jQuery('#rate-adjusted-' + key);
    //console.log(jQuery(rate_adjusted).val(rate * (1 + (percentage/100))));

    jQuery(rate_adjusted).attr('value', rate * (1 + (percentage/100)));

  });

}

jQuery(document).ready(function() {

  jQuery('#markup-override').change(function() {
    var percentage = jQuery(this).val();
    updateRateAdjusted(percentage);
  });


});
```

Once the user changes the inout value, the functions runs which changes the value in another hidden input value.

I have both tried **.val()** which does nothing as well as **.attr()** which only updates the **value** attribute in the DOM but does not change the visual value of the field.

The calculated values are all correct.

Does anybody know what I could be doing wrong?

Comment: .val() is the correct way to do this, and should have worked.

Comment: `rate_adjusted` is already wrapped with jquery wrapper..Try `rate_adjusted.val(rate * (1 + (percentage/100)))`;

Comment: @KartikeyaKhosla unfortunately still no luck for both .attr() or .val()

Comment: @MarcusChristiansen..check any error in console?

Comment: @KartikeyaKhosla no. no errors either.

Comment: alert `jQuery('#rate-adjusted-' + key).length` and check if there is any element with this id inside DOM.

Comment: your key for .each function starts from 0. where does your "<?php echo $row_count; ?>" start from?. var rate_adjusted = jQuery('#rate-adjusted-' + key); there might a mismatch at this line of code.

Comment: @KartikeyaKhosla only outputs 1. No other elements with same ID.

Comment: @AksheyBhat $row_count also starts from 0. It targets the right element because .attr() updates the value attribute but does not apply any visual changes.

Comment: I found the problem. The previous developer had added his own calculations which kept overriding mine.